# on click event not working after append tbody in ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, append, event-delegation

I am using php and mysql with jquery to display my data. The initial
time my `on` click event is working on `tbody`.

But when I append tbody with ajax call it's not working. I am using event delegation with `.on`

My html table :
I am using simple html table to display my data and onclick of any TD adding ajax to append data.

```
 <table id="NewsTable" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th-sm">Headline</th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Main Category</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                foreach($data as $val){ // php data foreach loop.(ignore)
                      <tr class='".$x++."className'> // using dynamic class name and id everywhere.
                  <td  class='".$x++."className1'><?php echo $val['data1']?></td>
                  <td  class='".$x++."className2'><?php echo $val['data2']?></td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        <table>
```

my ajax call :

```
$('#NewsTable').on('click','td', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: 'data',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#NewsTable tbody').empty();
                    $('#NewsTable tbody').append(response); // data is coming properly here. but Now on click event not working.
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                },
            });
});
```

Comment: have you tried setting the event to the document (since that would be a definete static object - `$(document).on('click','#NewsTable td', function(e){} );`

Comment: @Stender I doubt that would solve the issue, since OP says it already works on the initial load, indicating that #NewsTable is consistently present.

Comment: Amit, you haven't shown us the code of ajax.php I don't think. What does it return?

Comment: @ADyson well it is the same as the accepted answer, so it might have solved the issue anyway ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the selector to target the document like so:

```
$(document).on('click','#NewsTable td', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: 'data',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#NewsTable tbody').empty();
                    $('#NewsTable tbody').append(response); // data is coming properly here. but Now on click event not working.
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                },
            });
});
```

This code `$('#NewsTable tbody').empty();` is removing the elements which have listeners attached, and the new ones therefor do not have the click listeners after being appended.